# Is there an established file format for storing information needed to connect to a WiFi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, file-format

In particular, I'm curious if there's a file format used to encapsulate an SSID and security information about a wireless network which would allow it to be (in theory) exported from one device and imported to another.

It seems both iOS and Android support the same format for encapsulating a WiFi network as a QR code, but there doesn't seem to be anything similar that could store it in a file.

The closest thing I found is Microsoft's [WLANProfile XML file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/wlan-profileschema-wlanprofile-element), but this format seems only used on Windows (and even there, the only way to import it is via `netsh` in the command line).

Comment: If I were you I might test to see if the fake "wifi:" URL string that gets encoded in the QR codes works.

Comment: Scrolling down this page shows the entries included in the wifi: command: https://www.qr-code-generator.com/solutions/wifi-qr-code/ I don't know if there's a way to encode this in a file. I would guess that there is something defined in the QR specification that allows it to run encoded commands, much like a defined protocol ":\\"

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no established file format for transferring or communicating this sort of information.

As you've noted, QR codes allow this function by communicating some sort of pseudo-protocol. This isn't a real protocol. A protocol would be indicated by ":\", like a web link communicated via the Hyper Text Transfer Protocol, or HTTP:\ preceding website links. QR codes instead encode the WiFi connection information using a defined list of arguments which will communicate this information to the device reading the QR Code.

However, there is no defined or established format or method for conveying this information in a file format.